# Setting RSelenium in R

Tags: r, macos, selenium, rselenium

I'm trying to run a RSelenium file in R. I successfully installed RSelenium 1.7.1, wdman 0.2.2 and bin man 0.1.0 via devtools on MacOS 10.13.5.
My test R-file looks like following:

```
library(RSelenium)

# Start Browser
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
remDr$navigate(url)

# Click button 20 times:
i <- 1
while (i<20){
  try(remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".jscroll-next")$clickElement())
  i <- i + 1
  Sys.sleep(2)
}

# Smarter: Click button until all sites are loaded
run <- TRUE
i <- 1
while (run){
  tryCatch(
    remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".jscroll-next")$clickElement(),
    error= function(c) {run <<- F},
    warning = function(w) {run <<- F},
    finally = print(paste("Pressed button", i, "times"))
  )
  i <- i + 1
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

Every time I try to execute this R file I'm getting an error. This log file looks like this:

```
[Workspace loaded from ~/RSeleniumtest/.RData]

> library(RSelenium)
> 
> # Start Browser
> rD <- rsDriver()
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Fehler in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In rsDriver() : Could not determine server status.
> remDr <- rD[["client"]]
Fehler: Objekt 'rD' nicht gefunden
> remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
Fehler: Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
> remDr$navigate(url)
Fehler: Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
> 
> # Click button 20 times:
> i <- 1
> while (i<20){
+   try(remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".jscroll-next")$clickElement())
+   i <- i + 1
+   Sys.sleep(2)
+ }
Error in try(remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".jscroll-next")$clickElement()) : 
  Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
Error in try(remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".jscroll-next")$clickElement()) : 
  Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
Error in try(remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".jscroll-next")$clickElement()) : 
  Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
Error in try(remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".jscroll-next")$clickElement()) : 
  Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
Error in try(remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".jscroll-next")$clickElement()) : 
  Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
Error in try(remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".jscroll-next")$clickElement()) : 
  Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
Error in try(remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".jscroll-next")$clickElement()) : 
  Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
Error in try(remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".jscroll-next")$clickElement()) : 
  Objekt 'remDr' nicht gefunden
```

I know that this Script worked on other Windows 10 OS Systems so the problem should be my Mac. Because of the "Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused" I tried to disable my firewall in the settings but it didn't worked out.
Does someone know the answer to this problem?
Every help would be great!

Thanks a lot and regards

Comment: I would highly recommend running Selenium in a docker container instead of your mac. My personal experience with managing a package that employs Java in the background is that everything that has to do with Java on a Mac (such as Selenium) is an utter mess. So don't waste your time debugging theses issues and follow this instead: https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: can you try initialiszing remdr as remDr <- rD$client

Comment: Is an setup unter Windows OS easier? In this case I could install Windows via Bootcamp.
@Prany no this didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

Before running the R code, did you actually try to start selenium Webdriver in a separate terminal window? For me it looks like this,

I use this startup command in the directory where selenium.jar is located:

```
java  -Dhttp.proxyHost="" -Dhttp.proxyPort="" -jar selenium-server.jar -timeout 80 -browserSessionReuse

# selenium-server.jar is a symlink to selenium-XXXXX.jar
```

Output:_

```
13:02:40.659 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision 76d78cf
13:02:40.798 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
13:02:40.903 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
13:02:40.904 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
13:02:40.905 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
13:02:40.959 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@256216b3
13:02:40.960 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
13:02:40.960 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
13:02:40.960 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
13:02:40.964 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
13:02:40.965 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@65b3120a
13:02:54.799 INFO - Executing: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetAllSessions@5d5846cf)
13:02:54.802 INFO - Done: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetAllSessions@5d5846cf
```

Then I can run your R code in RStudio, with some minor modifications.